# Manuel segue 'Show' does not call ViedDidload when returning to parent viewController?

Tags: swift, xcode, segue, viewdidload

I have a viewController containing a UITableViewController. This UITableViewController is populated by an array. When User presses populated cells they segue with a segue set to 'Manuel Segue : Show' this creates a back button UINavigation bar item. Inside this viewController the user is able to add Items to the array populating the parent UITableViewController. The problem is that when i segue back using the UINavigationbarItem it does not call viewDidload on the UITableViewController, there by not updating the UIViewTableCells. I have to close application to make it call viewDidload... How do i make it call ViewDidload when returning from the Manuel segue show? All help appreciated.

Comment: `viewWillAppear` will be called.  Trigger a table reload from there.

Comment: Does this conflict with ViewDidLoad when the app launches?

Comment: `viewWillAppear` will be called after `viewDidLoad` the first time.  If you wanted to avoid calling `reload` that first time, you could set a property in `viewDidLoad` such as `viewJustLoaded = true` and skip the `reload` in `viewWillAppear` in that case.  Don't forget to set the property to false.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pushing view controller is not unloaded when another view controller is shown above. As **viewDidLoad:** is only called once in the view lifecycle,  this would then not be called when the segue is unwound.

Updating your tableview in **viewWillAppear:** or **viewDidAppear:** would cause this to be called whenever this view is displayed.

**viewWillAppear** would perhaps be better if you don't want to show the user the table reloading when not needing to asynchronously load data.

---

Read more on iOS view controller lifecycle here: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW3